# Browser stays blank

Tags: php, iis-6

I'm trying to set up some servers for php, more specific smtp send mails via php.
Anyway, on the first server everything went smooth, I could install it and run php files without a problem.
I installed the appropriate ISAPI extensions etc. For the second server I did the same, I also created a 'virtual directory' on the **default website**. But, everything stays blank in my browser. Even .html files
So not only .php but everything stays blank. Other websites on the IIS run normally.
I have to say that the other sites on the default website don't do much either.

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just uninstalled the new version of PHP, which was 5.3.x
Used the zipfile of an older 5.2.x version from [php.net/releases](http://php.net/releases) and unzipped it to C:\PHP
I followed this tutorial http://www.iisadmin.co.uk/?p=4

Also, I commented the line doc_root in the php.ini file and copied it to C:\PHP
Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Double check your PHP configuration, make sure that [session.save_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) points to a valid directory, and the user PHP is running under has Modify access.

Bear in mind that as of PHP 5.3 there is no ISAPI module, you will need to switch to FastCGI. Microsoft have produced a Web Platform Installer designed to get [PHP on Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/phponwindows.aspx) up and running quickly and correctly.